# Adicionar valor de Input como uma Option de um Select

Tags: javascript, html

Esse é o cenário:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title></title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="">
    <form>
      <input type="text">
      <button type="submit" name="Submit" onclick="addName">Add</button>
      <select class="" name="">
        <option value=""> - </option>
      </select>
    </form>
  </div>
  <script>
    function addName() {
      const lista = [{
        name: document.querySelector('input').value;
      }];

      // Select tag
      const selectOptions = document.querySelector('.selectOptions').option;

      lista.forEach(name => {
        selectOptions.add(
          new Option(option.name);
        )
      })
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Preciso pegar o valor inserido nesse input, e inserí-lo em uma array que será todo o conteúdo das opções desse select.
To travado nesse exercício, já pesquisei em tudo quanto é quanto, não achei uma solução. ;-;
Sou iniciante, se alguém puder dar uma luz eu agradeço!

Comment: Fiz mais algumas modificações no código, mas agora recebo o o valor de "undefined". --'

  function addName() {
    let selectMenu = document.querySelector('.mySelect');
    let option = document.createElement('option');
    let inputValue = document.querySelector('.inputName').text;

    selectMenu.add(option, inputValue);
    alert(inputValue);
  }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Precisas inserir o valor na tag com o **innerHTML** e adicionar a tag com o **appendChild**.

**Segue a correção:**

```
function addName() {
    let selectMenu = document.querySelector('.mySelect');
    let option = document.createElement('option');
    let inputValue = document.querySelector('.inputName');

    option.innerHTML = inputValue.value;

    selectMenu.appendChild(option);
    alert(inputValue);
}
```

**Dicas:**

1. É melhor usar **id** para selecionar as tags ao invés de **classes**, pois elas servem para estilos;
2. **Option** não precisa especificar **type="text**;
3. Como a **div** não tem classe, é melhor retirar ela.

Bons estudos!

Comment: Muito obrigado!

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title></title>
</head>
<style media="screen">
  .mySelect {
    width: 100px;
  }
</style>

<body>
  <div class="">
    <form>
      <input type="text" class="inputName">
      <button type="button" name="Button" onclick="addName()">Add</button>
      <select class="mySelect" name="">
        <option type="text"> - </option>
      </select>
    </form>
  </div>

</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
  function addName() {
    let selectMenu = document.querySelector('.mySelect');
    let option = document.createElement('option');
    let inputValue = document.querySelector('.inputName').text;

    selectMenu.add(option, inputValue);
    alert(inputValue);
  }
</script>

</html>
```

Após as alterações, mas ainda recebo "undefined". ;-;
Acho que to quase lá!